# Digitising image of plan/drawing

Tags: import, bentley

Does Bently have a way to import an image of a highway as point, lines, curves, etc. segments? I.e. digitise an image of a plan?

If something can do most of the hard work it would really help otherwise I have lots of tracing to do in Bentley or 12D model. If I can just get the lines that would really help.

Maybe there is a utility application I could use just to represent it as a dwg then I can bring it into Bentley like that.